# Wordpress set hom page Permalinks

Tags: wordpress

I want to set a page link to a new page from my home page. How do you do that?
No need for any post id follow the link [sic].

Comment: Is that a page showing in the menu of your site?!

Comment: No, that page not showing in the menu ,but i want to set in menu, just a page width no post id and post name such as http://www.example.com,but the Permalinks can not set that